# iOS 7 - How to set the cell separatorstyle to none for a particular section and singleline for other sections

Tags: objective-c, tableview, ios7

I want to set the empty view to a cell or no separator line for a particular section

```
if(section == 1)
self.documentTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
else
self.documentTable.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
```

If i do like above it is hiding separator line for all cells.Please help me .In iOS 6.0 i was doing like,

```
 buttonCell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can add cell layer width and colour. so that it will give rounded corners for the table.It will fix the problem..

Comment: The question makes sense but the answer is terrible, complicated and stupid.

Comment: if no other answers,u please tell the answer.. or else we have to find the successful alternatives.in apple maps they added rounded cells for to and from that style i followed,because that style is the apple default.

Comment: @Sulthan can you please upvote this.. as i have given an example of apple maps to and from fields for supporting my answer.why people always reject good things??

Comment: I will not upvote something that recommends adding a text field as a background...

Comment: @Sulthan hey boss that is Apple recommended boss.Pleas see the url https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/Controls.html

Comment: @Sulthan There is a control textfield control with start and end labels in that.I have designed like that.when apple has some documentation why you reject this.I want upvote please